# Add widget to desktop programmatically

Tags: android

I am developing a React Native app that exposes widgets.

Is there a way to add a widget to screen by just sending an intent to Android? Similar to sending an intent to open the browser or send the user to contacts?

It makes sense initially to me, but I am a bit ignorant on the topic.

Comment: I donno about React Native, but in Android if you write a widget and configure , then after installation the corresponding widget will appear in mobile phone's widget section. User needs to place the same in HomeScreen.

Comment: But this is not to add it programmatically, this means that a user has to call the activity of configuration after the installation. I would like the installation to happen without the user having to drag and drop the widget on screen.